# Concurrent assignment to a non-net is not permitted

Tags: verilog

I'm making module that make results according to cmd using 4 32-bit adder.
if cmd is 0, dout0 = a0+b0, and other dout is zero
if cmd is 1, dout1 = a1+b1 and other dout is zero.
if cmd is 2 or 3 likewise.
and if cmd is 4 dout0,1,2,3 makes former results.

The error message is:

> ERROR - VRFC 10-529 concurrent assignment to a non-net dout0 is not
> permitted ~/sim_1/new/adder_array.v:63

Why does this error happen, and how can I solve this problem?

here are code v.23~69.

```
module adder_array(
 cmd,
 ain0, ain1, ain2, ain3,
 bin0, bin1, bin2, bin3,
 dout0, dout1, dout2, dout3,
 overflow);

input [2:0] cmd;
input [31:0] ain0, ain1, ain2, ain3;
input [31:0] bin0, bin1, bin2, bin3;
output reg [31:0] dout0, dout1, dout2, dout3;
output [3:0] overflow;

wire [31:0] a[3:0];
wire [31:0] b[3:0];
wire [31:0] d[3:0];
wire ovf[3:0];

assign {a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]} = {ain0,ain1,ain2,ain3};
assign {b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]} = {bin0,bin1,bin2,bin3};
assign overflow = {ovf[3], ovf[2], ovf[1], ovf[0]};

parameter size = 4;

genvar i;
generate for(i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i = i + 1)
begin:adder
    if (i == 0) begin
     my_add adder(.ain(a[0]), .bin(b[0]), .dout(d[0]), .overflow(ovf[0]));
      end
    else if (i == size - 1 ) begin
      my_add adder(.ain(a[i]), .bin(b[i]), .dout(d[i]), .overflow(ovf[i]));
      end
    else begin
      my_add adder(.ain(a[i]), .bin(b[i]), .dout(d[i]), .overflow(ovf[i]));
      end
end
endgenerate

assign dout0 = (cmd == 0 || cmd == 4) ? d[0] : 0;
assign dout1 = (cmd == 1 || cmd == 4) ? d[1] : 0;
assign dout2 = (cmd == 2 || cmd == 4) ? d[2] : 0;
assign dout3 = (cmd == 3 || cmd == 4) ? d[3] : 0;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an `assign` statement, make `dout0` a `wire` type instead of `reg`.

I could write why you've encountered such error, but there already is an excellent answer by Cliff Cummings here: 
[How to 'assign' a value to an output reg in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809749/how-to-assign-a-value-to-an-output-reg-in-verilog/11234968#11234968)